# How do I make an empty catch block with F#?

Tags: f#

How can I create an empty catch block (or otherwise ignore all exceptions) in F#?

I'm working on code that creates a SQL Server database and schema.  Here's a sample:

```
let run (ipAddress : string) (port : int) (userName : string) (password : string) =
    let mutable maxTime = 0
    let mutable succeeded = false
    while not succeeded do
        try
            if maxTime > 120 then
                failwith "Unable to initialize SQL Server database in two minutes."
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
            maxTime <- maxTime + 5
            let con = new ServerConnection
                          (sprintf "%s,%i" ipAddress port, userName, password)
            let server = new Server(con)

            let db = new Database(server, "mydb")
            db.Create()

            let schema = new Schema(db, "myschema")
            schema.Create()

            succeeded <- true
        with
        // what goes here as the equivalent of: catch { }
```

If I get an exception that the database isn't available, I want to just ignore it and move on; the database is in a Docker container so sometimes it's slow to start up.

But what's the syntax to do that in F#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In F#, `try .. with ..` is an expression that evalautes to the result of one of the expressions that it contains. In imperative code, the result of these branches is a value of `unit` type which you can write as `()`.

So, in your example, the `with` branch of the `try .. with ..` needs to return a unit value - you can write that using something like:

```
let run (ipAddress : string) (port : int) (userName : string) (password : string) =
    let mutable maxTime = 0
    let mutable succeeded = false
    while not succeeded do
        try
            // all code omitted
        with _ ->
            ()
```